# Make links to hyperlinks in csv file through Python

Tags: python, csv, awk, sed, formatting

How can I make all links in the CSV file to hyperlinks? - Just add an HTML tag to all fields with links

I think it's possible through Python

CSV string looks like

```
"Name","CompanyName","Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6","Value7","Url","Value8 ""Value8.1"""
"Name","Company1","SomeValue1","SomeValue2","SomeValue3","SomeValue4","SomeValue5","SomeValue6","SomeValue7","https://company1.com","Some"Value8 ""Value8.1"""
"Name","Company2","SomeValue1","SomeValue2","SomeValue3","SomeValue4","SomeValue5","SomeValue6","SomeValue7","https://company2.com","Some"Value8 ""Value8.1"""
```

Should look like:

```
"Name","CompanyName","Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6", "Value7","Url","Value8"
"Name","Company1","SomeValue1","SomeValue2","SomeValue3","SomeValue4","SomeValue5","SomeValue6","SomeValue7","<a href="https://company1.com">https://company1.com</a>","Some"Value8 ""Value8.1"""
"Name","Company2","SomeValue1","SomeValue2","SomeValue3","SomeValue4","SomeValue5","SomeValue6","SomeValue7","<a href="https://company2.com">https://company2.com</a>","Some"Value8 ""Value8.1"""
"Name","Company3","SomeValue1","SomeValue2","SomeValue3","SomeValue4","SomeValue5","SomeValue6","SomeValue7","<a href="https://company3.com">https://company3.com</a>","Some"Value8 ""Value8.1"""
```

I tried awk and sed, but it makes a lot of mistakes when I specify a column in the file. I feel script just should find all links ant insert it to HTML tags. But I did not understand yet how  it works

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `csv` module, loop through the values. When your in the row you want, you can use the replace() method to create the hyperlink

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try it right now

Comment: Sorry I know it may not be a detailed/clear message, but I am caught up right now and wanted to give you a start. If you have trouble comment here and I will post a better answer

Comment: @Mykola Would you be willing to use pandas?

Comment: @Shubham, it doesn’t matter what to use, the main thing is to make hyperlinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example of how to do it. You can see examples of the csv module [here](https://realpython.com/python-csv/)

You examples data has some extra spaces - if your real data is like this you can use the `strip()` method to remove the whitespace.

If your URLs are not consistently in the same column than this won't work and you will need to use regex or urllib to identify them.

```
import csv

count = 0
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in csv_reader:
        row[0] = f'"{row[0]}'
        if count < 1:
            outfile.write('","'.join(row) + '"\n')
            count += 1
        else:
            row[-2] = f'<a href="{row[-2]}">{row[-2]}</a>'
            outfile.write('","'.join(row) + '"\n')
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, no extra spaces in original CSV file

Comment: @Mykola  No worries, one thing I forgot to mention is that depending on where the column is you need to edit you may need to replace both of those `-2`s with the correct index. And if you want to write the data back to a file the method will look very similar, just use `csv.writer()` instead

Comment: @Mykola I will edit the answer to include the writing portion - will you accept the answer as correct if it worked for you

Comment: @Mykola give this a try, let me know if there are any issues

Comment: It works almost fine, but in outfile.csv we lose double quotes in all columns besides column with hyperlinks

Comment: @Mykola  Ok, I'll fix it, standby

Comment: @Mykola Give this new one a try. I was getting a weird result where it was stripping quotes from the first value in each row. I manually added them, let me know if this works

Comment: sorry about that, but now I see error
"    csv_writer.writerow(row)
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set"

Comment: @Mykola  Did you set the `quotechar=` parameter correctly? Are you on Linux? I can test this on my linux box if you are. There my be a subtle difference between the OS

Comment: Yep, I use ubuntu
Which parameter I should set in quotechar=? I did set quotechar='"'

Comment: @Mykola  Set it the way I did - It should be empty quotes, nothing in there

Comment: the same error "    csv_writer.writerow(row)
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set" (

Comment: @Mykola  I just updated and removed the `csv.writer()`  Figured this would be faster than troubleshooting that module. Try this one. Works on mine

Comment: Almost
"Name",Company1,SomeValue1,SomeValue2,SomeValue3,SomeValue4,SomeValue5,SomeValue6,SomeValue7,"<a href=https://company1.com>https://company1.com</a>",SomeValue8
But if I little correcting "outfile.write('","'.join(row) + '\n')"
it looks almost well, but last column not have double quotes

Comment: Are you saying everything but the first line is missing quotes? I can fix that quick if that is the case

Comment: @Mykola  Could you edit into your question the results you are getting. If I can see exactly what the issue is I should be able to fix it quick.

Comment: I think I fix it.
I can publish all fixes there.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey @Joe
I have another problem with this issue
When I adding HTML tag, some parameters losing double-double quotes in some values.
How I can ignore it? I mean ignore double-double quotes look like this "field","anoter_field ""value_betweendouble-double_quotes""","field"
thanks in advance

Comment: @Mykola  I am a little unsure what you are asking or what the issue is. Maybe you can email me the example data, your expected result and your actual result. I need to see what is happening

Comment: Dear @Joe if you need more details, please let me know

Comment: @Mykola  Hey, I got your email, haven't had time to check it yet but I will get it done today.